# How do I integrate $\frac {\sin^3x}{\cos^2x}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

How do I integrate $\frac {\sin^{3}x}{\cos^{2}x}$. I have tried to convert to $\tan$, but I could not reach to conclusion. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $\sin^3 x= (1-\cos^2 x)\sin x $. Let $u=\cos x$

Comment: @DavidMitra Done Thanks

Comment: @TaylorTed The trigonometric functions such as $\sin$ and $\cos$ must be uprighted. Please use the correct notations.

Comment: Do you *Bioche's rules* to determine the relevant change of variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^2 x}dx$$
$$=\int \frac{(1-\cos^2 x)\sin x}{\cos^2 x}dx$$
Let $\cos x=t\implies -\sin x dx=dt$
$$=-\int \frac{(1-t^2)dt}{t^2}$$
$$=-\int (t^{-2}-1)dt$$
$$=-\left(-\frac{1}{t}-t\right)+c$$
$$=\frac{1}{t}+t+c$$
$$=\cos x+\sec x+c$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\int { \frac { \sin ^{ 3 }{ x }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  } dx=\int { \frac { \sin { x } \cdot \sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  } dx=-\int { \frac { 1-\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  } d\cos { x }  }  }  } =\\ =\int { d\left( \cos { x }  \right)  } -\int { \frac { 1 }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  } d\left( \cos { x }  \right) =\cos { x } +\frac { 1 }{ \cos { x }  } +C }  $$

Answer (score 2):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $\displaystyle \int\frac{\sin^3 x}{\cos^2 x}dx  = \int\frac{\sin^2 x \cdot \sin x}{\cos^2 x}dx = \int\frac{(1-\cos^2 x)\cdot \sin x}{\cos^2 x}dx $

Now Let $\cos x = t\;,$ Then $\sin xdx = -dt$

So Integral $\displaystyle I = -\int\frac{1-t^2}{t^2}dt = -\int \frac{1}{t^2}dt+\int 1\cdot dt=\frac{1}{t}+t+\mathcal{C}$

So $\displaystyle I = \frac{1}{\cos x}+\cos x+\mathcal{C}$